# Show PopUp with textbox when condition is met

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a textbox, I need to check the text entered by user using textchange event to see whether it is the one I want, if it is not, I want to display to the user a notification like the one here [example](http://www.drweb.de/img/tooltipps/form.gif)

I have tried the ModalPopupExtender in Ajax, and I made a panel as the PopupControlID, and I show the ModalPopupExtender only if the condition is not matched, the problem in this solution was that the popup panel is not shown under or next the textbox like the image in the example, I could not control its position to be near the textbox to tell the user this pop up message is for this textbox.

I have tried the BalloonPopupExtender too which will solve my problem regarding the place of the popup panel, but I found another problem, I could not control the show/hide of the BalloonPopupExtender, I can't show it when the condition is not met and hide it if met.

Please I need your advices..Thanks in advance

Comment: Which of the problems do you want to solve? Would you please show your code as well as your CSS? Cheers!

Comment: I want a solution for displaying a popup panel near the textbox when user enters invalid text, It's ok for me to be any solution either by modalpopupextender or ballonpopextender or any other suggestion